# Phonegap confirmation alert

Tags: ios, cordova, alert, confirmation

I tried putting the following code into a html and ran it and I uploaded it in my server and opened the link in my Safari browser in my iPhone and the clicked on Show Confirm and no window popups up! Can someone please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Notification Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://mobile-web-development-with-phonegap.eclipselabs.org.codespot.com/svn-history/r99/trunk/com.mds.apg/resources/phonegap/js/phonegap-1.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        // Wait for PhoneGap to load
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        // PhoneGap is ready        
        function onDeviceReady() {
            // Empty
        }
        // process the confirmation dialog result
        function onConfirm(button) {
            alert('You selected button ' + button);
        }
        // Show a custom confirmation dialog
                function showConfirm() {
            navigator.notification.confirm(
            'You are the winner!',  // message
            onConfirm,              // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
            'Game Over',            // title
            'Restart,Exit'          // buttonLabels
        );
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><a href="#" onclick="showConfirm(); return false;">Show Confirm</a></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are trying to use Phonegap APIs from a browser. They will only work if you make a native app with Phonegap. Make sure you understand what Phonegap is.

Answer (score 2):

The code that you are using (`navigator.notification.confirm`) is specifically for the mobile platform that is it is meant to run within the PhoneGap mobile application. If you would like to test out the dialogs/confirm messages on a browser before compiling it into an application, I would suggest using a hybrid approach that detects the environment of the application and uses either the native `confirm(message)` or the PhoneGap specific Notification API. Below is an example Object that has been working for me:

```
/**
 * The object encapsulates messaging functionality to work both in PhoneGap and 
 * browser environment. 
 * @author Zorayr Khalapyan
 * 
 */
var MessageDialogController = (function () {

    var that = {};

    /**
     * Invokes the method 'fun' if it is a valid function. In case the function
     * method is null, or undefined then the error will be silently ignored.
     *
     * @param fun  the name of the function to be invoked.
     * @param args the arguments to pass to the callback function.
     */
    var invoke = function( fun, args ) {
        if( fun && typeof fun === 'function' ) {
            fun( args );
        }
    };

    that.showMessage = function( message, callback, title, buttonName ) {

        title = title || "DEFAULT_TITLE";
        buttonName = buttonName || 'OK';

        if( navigator.notification && navigator.notification.alert ) {

            navigator.notification.alert(
                message,    // message
                callback,   // callback
                title,      // title
                buttonName  // buttonName
            );

        } else {

            alert( message );
            invoke( callback );
        }

    };

    that.showConfirm = function( message, callback, buttonLabels, title ) {

        //Set default values if not specified by the user.
        buttonLabels = buttonLabels || 'OK,Cancel';
        var buttonList = buttonLabels.split(',');

        title = title || "DEFAULT TITLE";

        //Use Cordova version of the confirm box if possible.
        if (navigator.notification && navigator.notification.confirm) {

                var _callback = function (index) {
                    if ( callback ) {
                        //The ordering of the buttons are different on iOS vs. Android.
                        if(navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad)/)) {
                            index = buttonList.length - index;
                        }
                        callback( index == 1 );
                    }
                };

                navigator.notification.confirm(
                    message,      // message
                    _callback,    // callback
                    title,        // title
                    buttonLabels  // buttonName
                );

        //Default to the usual JS confirm method.
        } else {
            invoke( callback, confirm( message ) );
        }

    };

    return that;

})();
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Where do I plug your code into? I am using Phonegap html can you upload a sample template file so i can test and learn.

Comment: Place the code inside a JavaScript file, and import it to your HTML page via <script> tag. You should be able to invoke the methods just by calling them i.e. `MessageDialogController.showConfirm("Hello World");`.

Comment: I did import the js into the html, I have trouble with the popup invoking the MessageDialogController.showConfirm("Hello World")

Can you provide a sample html code?

Comment: works great, except for the confirm callback! I get undefined on `test = MessageDialogController.showConfirm("Confirm")
  console.log(test)` ... any ideaS?

Comment: Ok.. so I found out phonegap controls work with callbacks. This works `MessageDialogController.showConfirm("Message",function(data){console.log(data)},'OK,Cancel','Title')`